# Document Library Sync does not work in FireFox of Safari

Tags: document-library, sync, firefox

I am trying to sync a document library to a Mac.  I have tried on Safari and Firefox.  I am logged into the Mac with an account that is an admin on the machine and a user of the website that has contributor permissions to the document library.  Any idea why this is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Sync will work in IE. Try IE browser.

Comment: well I cant force my users to use a specific browser :(